# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlshortener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting, google-api

I am receiving the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlshortener' of undefined

I am essentially trying to store into parse a url generated from google drive that has been shorten.

Below is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>upload</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
            var developerKey = 'ID';

            // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
            var clientId = 'ID';

            // Scope to use to access user's photos.
            var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

            var pickerApiLoaded = false;
            var oauthToken;

            // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
            function onApiLoad() {
                gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
                gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
            }

            function onAuthApiLoad() {
                window.gapi.auth.authorize(
                    {
                        'client_id': clientId,
                        'scope': scope,
                        'immediate': false
                    },
                    handleAuthResult
                );
            }

            function onPickerApiLoad() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
                createPicker();
            }

            function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                    createPicker();
                }
            }

            // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
            function createPicker() {
                if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
                    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
                        enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
                        addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).
                        setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
                        setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
                        setCallback(pickerCallback).
                        build();
                    picker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

            // A simple callback implementation.
            function pickerCallback(data) {
                var url = 'nothing';
                if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                    var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
                    url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                    var message =  url;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
                }

                var longUrl=url;
                var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
                    'resource': {
                        'longUrl': longUrl
                    }
                });
                request.execute(function(response) {
                    if(response.id != null) {
                        str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

                        Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
                        var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");

                        PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", response.id);

                        PDFUpload.save(null, {
                            success: function(uploadResult) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
                            },
                            error: function(uploadResult, error) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("error: creating short url");
                    }
                });
            }

            function load()
            {
                gapi.client.setApiKey('ID'); //get your ownn Browser API KEY
                gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});
            }
            window.onload = load;
        </script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div id="demo">
        <div id="output">
        <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In particular, this where I attempt to shorten the URL to store into Parse:

```
var longUrl=url;
var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
    'resource': {
        'longUrl': longUrl
    }
});
request.execute(function(response) {
    if(response.id != null) {
        str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

        Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
        var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");

        PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", response.id);

        PDFUpload.save(null, {
            success: function(uploadResult) {
                // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.

            },
            error: function(uploadResult, error) {
                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("error: creating short url");
    }
});
```

Update:
Please try out this code. It shortens a url from the input value you insert. In the sense that you enter example yahoo.ca in the input field, and once you hit convert it shortens it into a url and store in parse. This works succesfully, but I wanted to integrate that into my code where the url is derived from the url that is generated from the item the user has selected from their google drive:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>          
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function makeShort() {
                var longUrl=document.getElementById("longurl").value;
                var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
                    'resource': {
                        'longUrl': longUrl
                    }
                });
                request.execute(function(response) {
                    if(response.id != null) {
                        str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

                        Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
                        var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");

                        PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", response.id);

                        PDFUpload.save(null, {
                            success: function(uploadResult) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
                            },
                            error: function(uploadResult, error) {
                                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("error: creating short url");
                    }
                });
            }

            function load() {
                gapi.client.setApiKey('ID'); //get your ownn Browser API KEY
                gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});
            }
            window.onload = load;
        </script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        URL: <input type="text" id="longurl" name="url" value="yahoo.com" /> <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Create Short" onclick="makeShort();" /> <br/> <br/>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are you defining `gapi` or `gapi.client`?

Comment: thank you for your response. it is found in line 78, or more precisely: var longUrl=url;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
    'resource': {
      'longUrl': longUrl
    }
    });

Comment: I can't see where `gapi` is defined. If you are trying to call `gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert()` on something that is undefined, you will get the error. In your code, put `console.log(gapi)` before where you are getting your error. Check out the response and see if that object is defined and traverse what all of what is defined on it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to include that and added it at the bottom of the header as such:  function load()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey('ID'); //get your ownn Browser API KEY
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});
 
}
window.onload = load;
 
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>, but now it gives me the following error when it attempts to convert and store it in console: POST https://content.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?alt=json&key=AIzaSyDjs47QvxFvnGuh1EJS9_Jt-He0fXQk9S8 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Error: "message=Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."

Comment: Did you set it up? Not familiar with this library, but that error is pretty verbose

Comment: thank you for your response and for trying to help. To clarify the situation I have added an update under my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug through your example and tried to see what is going on, but I opted to start fresh and try to accomplish this in a simple way. I see that you are using Angular, so I made a little fiddle to try and shorten the url to this question.

The main issue I think, is that you need to generate a new key and follow the configuration steps. I did so in minutes and it worked fine. Be sure to choose the api you want (urlshortener) in your dashboard!

Here is the link I was able to generate http://goo.gl/15yWwP

```
function googleOnLoadCallback() {

    var key = '{ YOUR KEY }';

    var apisToLoad = 1; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
    var gCallback = function () {
        if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
            //Manual bootstraping of the application
            var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        };
    };
    gapi.client.setApiKey(key);
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', gCallback);
}

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleOnLoadCallback"></script>
```

And inside my `shorten()` function

```
var request = 
    gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
        'longUrl': '{ YOUR LONG URL }'
    });

request.execute(function(response) {
    console.log(response.id);
});
```

### [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/0hovpoea/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I guess the error is due to my API key as I tried your code and gave the same error  POST https://content.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?alt=json&key=AIzaSyBGmTbb9PasPuhofTl4lDGWDS5dAZAKQqg 403 (Forbidden i tried to create a new key but you think it could be due to the reference I am giving it to?  http://localhost:8080/ when its stored under http://localhost:8080/folder/scan.html

Comment: Did it work when you provided the new key? You should be able to plug it into my fiddle and see the shortened link

Comment: thanks for your quick response, and forgive my newbieness. I enter the key in your fiddle but is wondering how would it work when for my new api key the refers given was http://localhost:8080/